# swap 2 erc20 with each other at one method between 2 different user. -- Reentrancy guard problem

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I know I have to use nonReentrant modifier for this method, but I also know it's wont work can someone tell me what should I do to create a mechanism something like this with safe pattern?

```
function swapTokenToEvolve(uint256 _tokenAmount, uint256 _stageIndex)
public
checkStageTime(_stageIndex)
checkRemainingAmount(_tokenAmount, _stageIndex)
nonReentrant
returns (bool)
{
// get token price from stage ;
    uint256 tokenPrice = salesStages[_stageIndex].price;
// how many tokens user will get;
    uint256 stableTokenAmount = multiply(_tokenAmount, tokenPrice, decimal);
// transfer token from buyer to seller;
require(
    IERC20(currencyToken).transferFrom(
        owner(),
        _msgSender(),
        _tokenAmount
    )
);
// transfer token from seller to user;
require(
    IERC20(token).transferFrom(_msgSender(), owner(), stableTokenAmount)
);
salesStages[_stageIndex].liquidity = salesStages[_stageIndex]
    .liquidity
    .sub(_tokenAmount);
return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to use ReentrancyGuard here? If you're certain that `currencyToken` and `token` are safe you absolutely don't.

Comment: so you are saying this pattern is safe to swap tokens between 2 different guys at the same time ?

Comment: if I got miss understand please correct me. you are saying if these two tokens that's we use in this contract are trustable, I don't need to worry about reentrancy guard?

Comment: You understood it right :) maybe do some research on how reentrancy attacks work to understand why (and to learn how to defend against them withough using ReentrancyGuard)